# React Native ios and watchman

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, watchman

I'm trying to run my react native project (AwesomeProject) in macOS Catalina 10.15, watchman 4.9, XCode 11.1, ios 13.

it shows to me that Build Succeed, but the app couldn't be installed at this time, also the simulator shows this error in the running Metro:

Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.

**Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.**

**Error: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Operation timed out.** Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
Loading dependency graph, done.

Also is it okay that my simulator all the time shows black screen? can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours of searching... solved by myself, the error was in the ios 13.1, after downloading and installing ios 12 it works correctly.